24.04 Ubuntu crashes periodiocally, screen, keyboard and mouse freeze
On my recently (last month or two) installed Ubuntu 24.04 machine, i have recently experienced almost daily freezes or sudden restarts when i go away from the computer for some time. I have checked the important logs and nothing stands out. I know my pins on my Ryzer 7 1700 got a bent pint at some point and i bent it back, but thats years ago and suddenly this started to happen more frequently. Im not even sure if it has anything to do with the bent pin. I have ran cpu testing software and it passed. Altough the "kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 12: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: " looks awfully suspicious
Logs just before freeze:
15:49:06 bluetoothd: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
15:48:58 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: corrupted SCO packet
13:19:24 openvpn: event_wait : Interrupted system call (fd=-1,code=4)
12:32:20 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: SCO packet for unknown connection handle 257
12:31:43 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
12:31:41 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-user\x2ddirs\x2dupdate\x2dgtk-3344.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
12:31:37 pipewire: mod.adapter: usage: node.name=<string>
12:31:36 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
12:31:26 pipewire: spa.v4l2: '/dev/video0' VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL: Input/output error
12:31:25 kernel: usb 3-3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x86
12:31:24 canonical-livep: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/3f52a307a5b54dff91e8da3980e32ef1/updates" failed, retrying in 30s.
12:31:24 bluetoothd: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
12:31:24 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
12:31:21 kernel: 
12:31:21 kernel: usb 3-3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x86

Logs just after a sudden restart:
18:23:07 canonical-livep: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/3f52a307a5b54dff91e8da3980e32ef1/updates" failed, retrying in 1m30s.
18:23:07 canonical-livep: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/3f52a307a5b54dff91e8da3980e32ef1/updates" failed, retrying in 1m30s.
18:22:07 canonical-livep: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/3f52a307a5b54dff91e8da3980e32ef1/updates" failed, retrying in 1m0s.
18:21:54 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:54 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:54 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:54 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:54 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:54 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:54 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:54 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:54 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:53 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:53 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:53 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:53 kernel: [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00002600] Failed to grab modeset ownership
18:21:51 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-ubuntu\x2dreport\x2don\x2dupgrade-3400.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
18:21:51 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-ubuntu\x2dreport\x2don\x2dupgrade-3400.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
18:21:51 systemd: Failed to start app-gnome-snap\x2duserd\x2dautostart-3392.scope - Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
18:21:47 pipewire: mod.adapter: usage: node.name=<string>
18:21:46 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
18:21:39 pipewire: spa.v4l2: '/dev/video0' VIDIOC_QUERYCTRL: Input/output error
18:21:38 kernel: usb 3-3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x86
18:21:38 bluetoothd: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
18:21:38 kernel: usb 3-3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x86
18:21:38 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
18:21:37 canonical-livep: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/3f52a307a5b54dff91e8da3980e32ef1/updates" failed, retrying in 30s.
18:21:34 kernel: usb 3-3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x86
18:21:34 kernel: 
18:21:34 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read MSFT supported features (-19)
18:21:33 kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:800f11 TIME 1724775675 SOCKET 0 APIC 9 microcode 8001138
18:21:33 kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:800f11 TIME 1724775675 SOCKET 0 APIC 9 microcode 8001138
18:21:33 kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR 1ffffb502d0a2 MISC d012000100000000 SYND 4d000000 IPID 500b000000000 
18:21:33 kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 12: Machine Check: 0 Bank 5: bea0000000000108

Basic system details:
# System Details Report
---

## Report details
- **Date generated:**                              2024-08-27 17:52:42

## Hardware Information:
- **Hardware Model:**                              MSI MS-7A37
- **Memory:**                                      32.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   AMD Ryzen™ 7 1700 × 16
- **Graphics:**                                    NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3060
- **Disk Capacity:**                               1.7 TB

## Software Information:
- **Firmware Version:**                            A.M6
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               46
- **Windowing System:**                            X11
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.8.0-41-generic

Full report from lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
    Flags: fast devsel

00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 25
    Capabilities: [40] Secure device <?>
    Capabilities: [64] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [74] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+

00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 0

00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26, IOMMU group 1
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [32-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fc900000-fc9fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
    Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [370] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [3c4] Designated Vendor-Specific: Vendor=1022 ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=44 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27, IOMMU group 2
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=25, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: f000-ffff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fc500000-fc7fffff [size=3M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
    Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [370] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [3c4] Designated Vendor-Specific: Vendor=1022 ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=44 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 3

00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 4

00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28, IOMMU group 5
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=26, subordinate=26, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: e000-efff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fb000000-fc0fffff [size=17M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: d0000000-e1ffffff [size=288M] [32-bit]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
    Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [370] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [3c4] Designated Vendor-Specific: Vendor=1022 ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=44 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 6

00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 7

00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29, IOMMU group 8
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=27, subordinate=27, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [32-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fc200000-fc4fffff [size=3M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
    Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 9

00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31, IOMMU group 10
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=28, subordinate=28, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [32-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fc800000-fc8fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
    Capabilities: [c8] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] FCH SMBus Controller
    Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel, IOMMU group 11
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] FCH LPC Bridge
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 11

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 12

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 12

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 12

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 12
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp

.....

01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd SSD 980 PRO
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39, IOMMU group 13
    Memory at fc900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=130 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [168] Alternative Routing-ID Interpretation (ARI)
    Capabilities: [178] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [198] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [1bc] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
    Capabilities: [214] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [21c] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [3a0] Data Link Feature <?>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

03:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. 300 Series Chipset USB 3.1 xHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 75, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at fc7a0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=8/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [200] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [300] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [400] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

03:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset SATA Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. 300 Series Chipset SATA Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at fc780000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Expansion ROM at fc700000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

03:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43b2 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 0201
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32, IOMMU group 14
    Bus: primary=03, secondary=20, subordinate=25, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: f000-ffff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fc500000-fc6fffff [size=2M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Upstream Port, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 0201
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33, IOMMU group 14
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=21, subordinate=21, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [32-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fc600000-fc6fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [200] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [400] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 35, IOMMU group 14
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=22, subordinate=22, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: f000-ffff [size=4K] [16-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: fc500000-fc5fffff [size=1M] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [200] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [400] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36, IOMMU group 14
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=25, subordinate=25, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled] [32-bit]
    Memory behind bridge: [disabled] [32-bit]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled] [64-bit]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [c0] Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [200] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [400] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

21:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
    DeviceName: Broadcom 5762
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200NGW
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at fc600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

22:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34, IOMMU group 14
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Memory at fc504000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fc500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-68-4c-e0-00
    Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [178] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

26:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GA106 [GeForce RTX 3060 Lite Hash Rate]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 115, IOMMU group 15
    Memory at fb000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at fc000000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [258] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [bb0] Physical Resizable BAR
    Capabilities: [c1c] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [d00] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
    Capabilities: [e00] Data Link Feature <?>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

26:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GA106 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 111, IOMMU group 15
    Memory at fc080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [160] Data Link Feature <?>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

27:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 16
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services

27:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor (PSP) 3.0 Device
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor (PSP) 3.0 Device
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 92, IOMMU group 17
    Memory at fc300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at fc400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/2 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=2 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Kernel driver in use: ccp
    Kernel modules: ccp

27:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) USB 3.0 Host Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) USB 3.0 Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 84, IOMMU group 18
    Memory at fc200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=8/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

28:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Renoir PCIe Dummy Function
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Renoir PCIe Dummy Function
    Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 19
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [270] Secondary PCI Express
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services

28:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42, IOMMU group 20
    Memory at fc808000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/16 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] SATA HBA v1.0
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

28:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 113, IOMMU group 21
    Memory at fc800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [2a0] Access Control Services
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

Anyone with tips?
EDIT: marked driver issue answer as the answer

Got a new sudden restart. Its looking mroe and more like a cpu issue than an nvidia issue. I updated the driver to 560 and freezing seems to have stopped.
06:50:52 kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:800f11 TIME 1724818945 SOCKET 0 APIC 6 microcode 8001138
06:50:52 kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:800f11 TIME 1724818945 SOCKET 0 APIC 6 microcode 8001138
06:50:52 kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 MISC d012000100000000 SYND 2d030000 IPID b000000000
06:50:52 kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 3: Machine Check: 0 Bank 0: baa0000000060185
is this bad cpu?

This is an NVIDIA driver issue, causing a kernel panic.  Can you try and roll-back the NVIDIA driver to the previous version?

Your "bent pin" is causing an intermittent connection. Take the card to a reputable repair shop, and have the pin replaced. Software doesn't like intermittent hardware. Imagine the software is like "Write this, and do that, and", and your card is like "Hi, I'm back".

Im getting mixed feedback here  the bent pin was on the amd CPU. Ill try revert nvidia version first

but to double check @andor-kiss you are saying the proprietary and tested driver version 535 of nvidia might have an issue?

downgraded to 470 now. Ill see how it goes. If it continues to crash, i have a different kind of problem. Maybe the cpu ;)

upgrading to 560 and testing that instead ..  can still run steam games.. even if it complains its "missing" i386 drivers and stuff

the machine survived a night where it stood 2 hours untouched, then went to sleep and then woke up now. With no crashes. So for me it seems to have solved itself with upgrading the driver the latest driver available, for now. Unsure however if this answer should be marked as the solution, but it was the answer that kicked me into messing with nvidia drivers

nah, sudden restart still happens and logs show its hardware error related to cpu. But maybe i have mitigated the screen and input freeze at least.
